# Why does this provide me with a stack overflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

The following code yields a stack overflow error, can someone tell me why?
(I know how to fix the error, if I reference 'super' instead of 'this' in the `add` method, but I am not sure why that works.)

```
package subclassingVector;

import java.util.Vector;

public class MyVectorSubclass extends Vector<MyModelClass> {

    public MyVectorSubclass(){
        MyModelClass m = new MyModelClass();
        m.setId(2);
        this.add(m);
        if(this.contains(m)){
        System.out.println("contains is true");
    }
    }


    public boolean add(MyModelClass o){
            this.add(o);
            return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o){
            for(subclassingVector.MyModelClass mmc: this){
                if(mmc.equals((MyModelClass) o)){
                    return true;

                }
            }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = new String("SSEE");
        MyVectorSubclass m = new MyVectorSubclass();

    }

    public class MyModelClass {

        private Integer id = null;

        public MyModelClass() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you get a `StackOverflowError`, looking at the stack trace of the Error should be informative; walk through the logic using the given line numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code calls itself, forever, hence the StackOverflowError:

```
public boolean add(MyModelClass o){
    this.add(o);
    return true;
}
```

The `this` represents the instance of the object that the current method is being called on. In fact, the above code, in this context, is precisely the same as:

```
public boolean add(MyModelClass o){
    add(o);
    return true;
}
```

This code does something entirely different:

```
public boolean add(MyModelClass o){
    super.add(o);
    return true;
}
```

That doesn't make a recursive call. That simply calls the implementation of `add()` in the base class.

Cory Kendall's comment on the question is very valuable:

> If you get a `StackOverflowError`, looking at the stack trace of the Error should be informative; walk through the logic using the given line numbers.

The stack traces of an exception can give you a lot of useful information about the origin of the problem. In this case, the stack trace would clearly show that `MyVectorSubClass.add()` is repeatedly calling itself in the case of `this.add(o)`.

I suggest taking a look at:

- [Tutorial on inheritance (includes `super`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
- [Tutorial on objects (includes `this`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/more.html)

Comment: OP is looking for `super.add()` possibly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's clear what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: My goal is to create a Vector subclass that I can use with models and only allow certain models to be added, and to create an effective override of the contains method, to check for model ids instead of object ids, which I admit, I should probably understand better.